# Include or discard non-significant coefficients in the total Y estimate/calculation?

Tags: regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model, interaction, regression-coefficients

In *Y= b0 + b1x1 + b2x2 + b3 x1 * x2* where e.g. b1 is not significant. What is the correct estimate (calculation) for Y?

- Since b1 is **not** significantly different from 0, wouldn't a correct interpretation be the exclusion of said parameter b1x1? That is, despite b_1 changing the resulting Y estimate if included in the total estimation/calculation for Y.
- Note: "Include" here refers to inclusion of the non-significant coefficient in the sum of coefficients to calculate the overall estimate *Y*. That is, the model that is run to reach said estimates remains unchanged.

More specifically, working with a logistic regression where *b = log(OddsRatio)*, including the non-significant OR of b1 changes the resulting OR interpretation. Example: b1 and b2 are the coefficients for binary, dummy-coded factors.

- Note, coefficients in OR. Hence OR*OR instead of logOR+logOR.
- 1.7(b1) * 1.5(b2) * 0.5(b3-interaction)= 1.28
- 1.7(b1) * 0.5(b3-interaction) = 0.85

Taking the non-significant effect into account, the estimated change in odds is a factor of 1.28 (an increase from the reference group). On the other hand, excluding said non-significant effect, the resulting odds ratio is 0.85 (hence, a decrease compared to the reference group).

Consequently the question:

- Should non-significant estimates be included in the calculation?
- Given the coefficient is non-significant it should not (reliably) change the estimate either way. I would thus assume b=0 / OR=1. Is that not correct?
- Since the non-significant model coefficient is in fact not b=0 / OR=1, I wonder if I would insensibly alter the Y estimate if I discard the non-significant coefficient. Discarding here refers to including a NULL input, hence, b=0 / OR=1, which would simply not take into account any effect of said coefficient. Yet, again, I wonder if that would insensibly/incorrectly alter the estimate Y.

Perhaps someone could help clarify the role of non-significant coefficients in a model when estimating Y, and how one should interpret/deal with such non-significant coefficients when calculating the estimate Y.

Thank you!

Comment: It might help to think of the "non-significant coefficient" not as having a definite value, but as being so uncertain that it possibly could be zero. When the degree of uncertainty is sufficiently large, it could translate to large uncertainty in any estimate associated with the regression.  It might also help to consider the case where you aren't including the "non-significant" variable to test it, but because theory demands its inclusion in the model. This suggests that a proper answer to your questions depends on what you hope to accomplish with this modeling exercise.

Comment: @Glen_b Do you refer to the example, hence 1.28 and 0.85? Those are the summed coefficients in from exp(b), since b in logistic regressions is the log(oddRatio) describing the observed change/effect in Y. Hence, instead of b1x1 + b2x2, it is exp(b1)x1 * exp(b2)x2. Here, x will simply be a dummy (0 or 1).

Hence, the right hand "Y" describes the change in Odds (for Y) from that of the reference group to that of the group XYZ, whichever the X values describe. E.g. Group x_1 = 1, x_2 = 1, instead of the group where both X = 0.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for the kind reply. Yes, that is correct. The factor is indeed one that should remain included. However, exactly due to the "uncertainty" (= non-significance), I wonder what best describes Y? In my (naive) understanding, I thought no effect, since no effect is "certain" enough to be claimed "significant." Hence, b=0 or OR = 1, seemed sensible. However, the model does in fact not define b as 0. So, despite its uncertainty, its value is unequal to 0. Here, I suppose, the essence of my question: What does the model take into account that it makes more sense for b to not be 0?

Comment: @whuber Actually, I thought about this a bit more and now think the following: Uncertainty of the estimate is the predominant reason for its non-significance. However, the central value of the coefficient is still unequal 0--hence, the observed b value. Consequently, it seems, as long as the uncertainty is reported, the observed b estimate is more sensible then replacing it with b=0, since that would further deviate from its central tendency without any reasoning other than to fully exclude its (conditional) effects. At least for now, I find such replacement seems more artificial.

Comment: @Glen_b I think you noticed a typo of mine. b3x1*x2 is referring to the interaction of x1 and x2.